# Can we create a Custom category in Vimeo? Is there any API available for that?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Can we create a Custom category?
Is there any API available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The [Categories on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/categories) are hard-coded and are intended for discovery of public videos. API documentation for Categories is found on the [Vimeo Developer Site](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/categories).

If you want to do some kind of self-categorization for organization purposes, try using [Folders](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011969887-Folders) instead. API docs are also on the [dev site](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders).